# Hiding GET variables with sockets

Tags: perl, http

I have a script where i send a GET request to a page. Im trying to figureout how to surpress the output, here is the code itself:

```
use  IO::Socket;
my $domain = 'yahoo.com';

$socket=IO::Socket::INET->new(
                                Proto => 'tcp',
                                PeerAddr => $domain,
                                PeerPort => '80',
                                ) or return $!;
print $socket "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
print $socket "Host: ", $domain, "\r\n";
print $socket "Connection: close", "\r\n";
print $socket "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)", "\r\n";
print $socket "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*", "\r\n\r\n";

print while <$socket>;
```

Here is the output.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.27-1~dotdeb.0
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=k2bviiurukqdju1l26j4fat0q0; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sun, 18 May 2014 19:53:20 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
X-Page-Speed: 119_1_jt
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic

Apache works!
```

As you can see it shows the full page headers at the top, i just want the page output.
How could i suppress the output of the server headers? And just keep the page data.

Comment: If you are using a raw Socket interface to talk to an HTTP Server, you will get the entire response because the socket doesn't understand `http`, only bit streams. You will have to read the response into a variable and filter it yourself if you want to go this route.

Comment: Use an HTTP library ? e.g. http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/lwp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to make web requests, it is almost always better to just use an `http` library.

For this particular case, however, the following should also suffice. It simply prints everything after the first line with only `\r\n`, because that is the delimiter used to separate the headers from content in the `http` protocol.

```
# The following line has been replaced with the loop
# print while <$socket>; 

$seennl = 0;
while (<$socket>) {
    if ($seennl) {
        print;
    }
    elsif ($_ eq "\r\n"){
        $seennl=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked perfect, but it does print a newline before the actual data which i can fix myself.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) specifies that the headers and the contents are separated by an empty line. Therefore, you can just discard everything until the first empty line:

```
my $print = 0;
while (<$socket>) {
    chomp;
    if ($print) {
        print $_, "\n";
    }
    elsif ($_ eq '') {
        $print = 1;
    }
}
```

It would be easier, and you would handle special cases better, if you used a module such as [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent):

```
use LWA::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://yahoo.com/index.php' );
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend that you heavier weight module like [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) or [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) instead of recreating the wheel.  There's a helpful 8 minute video introduction to the latter in [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

However, because the spec for HTTP is to separate the header by a blank line, you can just do an initial read in paragraph mode to skip the header:

```
# Skip Header
{
    local $/ = "";
    <$socket>;
}

print while (<$socket>);
```